# clean to check if dtype is an instance of a type?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find a clean way to check if a column dtype is int , int64 ,bool whatever....
Currently I'm checking the first value type. I don't find it clean at all. It could be null , there could be mixed type for some reasons. 
Does anyone think of a more robust way ?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import json
    from random import randint,choice,random
    import string

    def random_character():
        return choice(string.ascii_letters)
    def random_string(length=4):
        string_random = random_character()
        for i in range(length - 1):
            string_random += random_character()
        return string_random
    def random_df(nb_rows=7):
        out = []
        for i in range(nb_rows):
            out.append({
                'A': randint(0, 10),
                'B': random_string(),
                'C': round(random(), 2) * 100,
                'D': bool(randint(0, 1))
            })
        return pd.DataFrame(out)
    rdf=random_df(3)
    print(rdf.A.iloc[0],type(rdf.A.iloc[0]))
    print(isinstance(rdf.A.iloc[0],int64))
```

[image: example of execution]

Comment: Maybe start with `df.apply(np.dtype)`?

Comment: isinstance(rdf['A'].dtype, int64)   returns False , as 'rdf['A'].dtype' is in fact numpy.dtype

Comment: `np.issubdtype(rdf['A'].dtype, np.int64)`

Comment: found a yet-not-so-clean but slightly better solution using str(rdf['A']) and then matching strings casted types

Comment: and finally this one : np.issubdtype(rdf['A'],int)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
import numpy as np
rdf.A.dtype is np.dtype('int64') 
# True
```